# Mapping a windows git directory into a linux docker container

Tags: git, docker, window, volumes

I want to map a folder on a windows machine which contains code from a git repository into a linux docker container.
I then connect via vscode and ssh to that container and open the mapped folder.

> **The issue is**: when the folder is opened, vscode shows all text based files as "modified", Even though those files do not have any pending changes on the host file system.

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  srv:
    image: image:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "22:22"
    volumes:
      - ./:/workdir
```

My expected behavior would be to see no difference in the "modified" state of the files between host and container.

I made sure that all files have a "LF" line ending. I even tried to run `dos2unix` on all files from that repository from within the container but nothing changed.

I guess I have to try to check out the code directly into the container. However I am still curious why this happens.

I would be greatful if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: I'm not totally clear where Docker comes into this.  Can't you check out the repository and edit directly on the host system, without injecting it into a container first?

Comment: I could. But I want to develop on Linux and I do not want to use a VM. Neither do I want to use Dev-Containers. Since even though MS is busy making dev containers a standard, as of now its only used by vscode (and maybe some other MS products). At least thats the extend of my knowledge.

Remote SSH is more broadly supported. Thats why I've chosen this approach.

Comment: Try to run a `git diff HEAD` to check the diff. The command line version will actually show more information, including permission changes (it's called `modes` in git diff), which might be the change you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem, here https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/connect-multiple-containers I found out that you have to put the "cached" param in your `docker-compose.yml` file, like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  srv:
    image: image:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "22:22"
    volumes:
      # Mount the root folder that contains .git
      - .:/workdir:cached
```

and to solve the many modified files I put this in my `.gitignore` file:

```
 * text=auto eol=lf
*.{cmd,[cC][mM][dD]} text eol=crlf
*.{bat,[bB][aA][tT]} text eol=crlf
```

and run
`git config --global core.autocrlf input` on the host computer (not inside the docker container) make sure you rebuild the container:

- on Dev Containers: (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows/Linux, Cmd+Shift+P on macOS) and searching for "Dev Containers: Rebuild Without Cache and Reopen in Container"
- on Docker: `docker-compose build --no-cache backend`

here is a full explanation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_resolving-git-line-ending-issues-in-wsl-resulting-in-many-modified-files

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution for the mapping to work. I ended up cloning my code inside the container. That got rid of the issue.